# Can users clear the service worker cache?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've built a Progressive Web App that uses caching, but it's unclear to me whether users can (accidentally or on purpose) clear the service worker cache, which may clear my tracking data.

Answer (score 7):

When a user clears their browsing data / cookies, this clears all site storage which includes the SW cache, cookies, local storage, indexeddb, and any other local caching system.

Comment: Note this will also unregister all service workers, meaning you won't be in a scenario where your service worker is registered and controlling a page without the any of the cached assets from the install step.

Comment: How do we do this for Chrome on Android? If I go to site settings and "clear & reset", it doesn't clear the SW cache or the PWA shortcut from the phone.

Comment: K, appears that it is installed in the appdrawer now and you just uninstall as you would any other app.

Comment: How can we clear localStorage and cache on chrome when uninstalling the PWA ? I have created apk for PWA app and when I am uninstalling and install again , I can see my storage information still prevails.

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, `Ctrl-F5` forces a cache refresh, and  is `intended to abandon all cached content including service worker cache` and just retrieve all content from the servers again.

Comment: Does it clear the app data even if the pwa is installed on the android phone?

Answer (score 0):

"Clear site data" in Chrome 76 will delete the caches and the worker, however the deleted worker remains "activated and running". So that's a case that needs dealing with.