# Does clearing the Browser Data also clear out the data of a PWA?

Tags: browser-cache, progressive-web-apps

I'm new to PWA and had this question bugging me. If a user clears out the browser data, will it also clear out the data which is stored by a Progressive Web App, as it depends on the browser for it's execution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it would. This is confirmed by a Google Engineer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38709996/6143482):

> When a user clears their browsing data / cookies, this clears all site
>   storage which includes the SW cache, cookies, local storage,
>   indexeddb, and any other local caching system.
>
> Note this will also unregister all service workers, meaning you won't
>   be in a scenario where your service worker is registered and
>   controlling a page without the any of the cached assets from the
>   install step.