# Do/Can PWAs on Android run in an isolated container or sandbox?

Tags: android, ios, .net, progressive-web-apps

In later iOS versions, PWAs run in their own container. Cookies are NOT shared among other PWAs or Safari browsers. HOWEVER, on **Android** devices with a Chrome Browser, I have my doubts based on my experience so far. If saved to homescreen with a *PARTIAL* implementation of the manifest (e.g. missing a 512px image), it only saves effectively as a bookmark, and although `start_url` and most other `manifest.json` properties are honored, it still shares cookies, etc. with a Chrome mobile browser.

If saved in full compliance with the [spec](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/), I still can't get it to operate in it's own container. BTW - more [conflicting] manifest image info from Lighthouse [HERE](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/custom-splash-screen).

Any experiences from the wild?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that a PWA does not run in any kind of isolated container on Android.

A PWA installed via Chrome shares its cache (IndexedDB, LocalStorage, Cache API, etc) with the Cache of the same application's origin in Chrome.

This has some significant consequences. For example, if I clear my Chrome browser cache on Android, it can be seen that cached data has been cleared when I open the PWA via its shortcut (see [Can users clear the service worker cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709981/can-users-clear-the-service-worker-cache/38709996#38709996)).

Comment: Dang. I seriously do NOT understand how the PWA push will be successful without isolated containers. Surely if Apple can do it the Google Monster can do it.